# Post IEnumerable collections from view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application, populating dropdownlist to view working fine in get method. I am populating to view like this in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateEmployeeFamilyDetails(EmployeeSuperClass employeeSuperClass, int i = 0)
{
    employeeSuperClass.FamilyDetailsFields = new FamilyList();
    employeeSuperClass.FamilyDetailsFields.familyMembersList.Insert(0, new EmployeeFamilyTable());
    *employeeSuperClass.FamilyDetailsFields.employee_RelationTable = dt.GetRelations();*
    *employeeSuperClass.FamilyDetailsFields.employee_BloodGroupTable = dt.GetBloodGroups();*
    *employeeSuperClass.FamilyDetailsFields.employee_NationalityTable = dt.GetNationalities();*

    return View("CreateEmployeeFamilyDetails", employeeSuperClass);
}
```

Please look into starred lines

In case if there is any errors in model am getting null reference

In post action method look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEmployeeFamilyDetails(EmployeeSuperClass employeeSuperClass, string Command)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return("some view");
  }
  else
  {
    return view(employeeSuperClass);
  }
}
```

I know again we have to create instance to populate dropdownlist this is rubbish to do same again and again

Can anyone explain how to store dropdown list collection in view separately and post them also with model? 
(note: `employee_relationTable` is `IEnumerable` collection and it is a relationtable type this table contains relation id and relationname fields and am using this table in this class like below

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeRelationTable> employee_RelationTable { get; set; }
```

For rest also am using same approach

Can we post `employee_RelationTable` from view and how?

Please help and your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should't. Sending all that data to the client and then back again across the wire would just slow your app. Create a private function that populates the data and call it from both the GET and POST methods and if your worried about the database calls, consider storing the collections in session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `dt` is a member field available to all methods, what you can do is DRY up the population of the DropDowns in the View Model in a separate method, e.g.

```
private void PopulateDropDownsOnViewModel(EmployeeSuperClass model)
{
    model.FamilyDetailsFields = new FamilyList
    {
        employee_RelationTable = dt.GetRelations(),
        employee_BloodGroupTable = dt.GetBloodGroups(),
        employee_NationalityTable = dt.GetNationalities()
    }
 }
```

Which can be used in the `Get`:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult CreateEmployeeFamilyDetails(EmployeeSuperClass employeeSuperClass, int i = 0)
 {
     PopulateDropDownsOnViewModel(employeeSuperClass);
     return View("CreateEmployeeFamilyDetails", employeeSuperClass);
 }
```

and in the `Post` (and any other controller actions which need the drop downs)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEmployeeFamilyDetails(EmployeeSuperClass employeeSuperClass, string Command)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return("some view");
     }
     else
     {
          PopulateDropDownsOnViewModel(employeeSuperClass);
          return View(employeeSuperClass);
     }
 }
```

If the drop downs are static, you can also look at caching these to prevent wasted IO to the database.

But no, don't serialize the the data in the View somehow (remember `WebForms ViewState`?) or fetch data from the View directly - this violates the MVC paradigm - the controller is responsible for providing data for the View to render.